# load youtube iframe_api on demand and then use it

Tags: ajax, jquery

I have a page that can be deployed in an offline situation, and want to handle playing youtube videos in a particular container on screen. I don't want to load iframe_api from youtube until it's needed, since there's a large chance it won't be.

```
function EmbedAndPlay_Youtube(videoid, container) {
// todo: allow script caching
$.getScript("//www.youtube.com/iframe_api")
    .fail(function () {
        // some kind of alert to the user ...
    })
    .done(function () {
        var $container = $(container);
        var w = $(container).width(),
            h = $(container).height(),
            player = new YT.Player('ytvideo', {
                height: h,
                width: w,
                videoId: videoid,
                events: {
                    'onReady': function (event) {
                        event.target.playVideo(); 
                    }
                }

            });
    });
}
```

sometimes, depending on the platform and its network capability, I get a script undefined kind of error, which I *think* means that the "done" function has executed before the youtube script has finished executing itself.

Is there a way to ensure that the loaded script has finished executing before calling a "done" method?

Comment: Are you sure jQuery is loaded before you're trying to use it?

Comment: yes. guaranteed. it seems (with my testing) to be more problematic on a 3G connection (but not a 4g connection).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem there is that the script loaded async in the url `//youtube.com/player_api` loads another script asynchronously (the JS player itself, which defines YT.Player). In your case, your `done()` callback is called when the script is loaded, but the player script may not be loaded yet. (*Technically, the script in `//youtube.com/player_api` is just a loader*)

To use YT.Player safely, bind your callback to `window.onYouTubeIframeAPIReady`, which is called by YouTube's script:

```js
function EmbedAndPlay_Youtube(videoid, container) {
    $.getScript("//www.youtube.com/iframe_api")
    .fail(function () {
        // some kind of alert to the user ...
    })
    .done(function () {
        window.onYouTubeIframeAPIReady = function () {
            var $container = $(container);
            var w = $(container).width(),
            h = $(container).height(),
            player = new YT.Player('ytvideo', {
                height: h,
                width: w,
                videoId: videoid,
                events: {
                    'onReady': function (event) {
                        event.target.playVideo(); 
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
```